# Bash Command Templating For Docker

Tags: bash, shell, docker

I have a commonly typed and now tedious command to start and link a docker container. It's something like:

```
docker run -d --name my-running-container --link app:some-app-command --link rabbitmq:amq --link mysql:db --link neo4j:neo --link solr:solr my-image
```

I would prefer to just execute:

```
docker run --name my-running-container my-image
```

How can i achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple bash script named docker or whatever name you like:

```
#!/bin/bash
DOCKER=`which docker`
$DOCKER run -d --name $1 --link rabbitmq:amq --link mysql:db --link neo4j:neo --link solr:solr $2
```

and then run it like `./docker my-running-container my-image`

The same thing could be achieved with bash alias:

```
alias docker='docker run -d --name $1 --link rabbitmq:amq --link mysql:db --link neo4j:neo --link solr:solr $2'
```

If you want to save the alias just add it at the end of `~/.bash_aliases` and reload your shell.